# How can I remove a class from a list with less code?

Tags: c#

Here is a class:

```
public class ABC
        {
            public string A;
            public string B;
        }
```

I want to remove the class from the list which A equal 123.So here is the code:

```
List<ABC> L = new List<ABC>();
            ABC ClassToRemove=null;
            foreach (ABC Single in L)
            {
                if (Single.A == "123")
                {
                    ClassToRemove = Single;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (ClassToRemove != null)
            {
                L.Remove(ClassToRemove);
            }
```

This code can do that.However I think it is so long and ugly.I wonder if there is a faster way to do it and the code is much more better?

Comment: Clarify what you mean by "faster". Do you mean that the code should actually run faster, or that it should be less code?

Comment: @JLRishe means less code.haha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to just remove objects from the list using LINQ.

Like this,

```
List<ABC> L = new List<ABC>();

// Insert data into list

// Line to remove item with specific requirements
L.RemoveAll(x => x.A == "123");
```

Comment: LINQ will be a bit slower because it introduces overhead. Do not use LINQ if you care much about performance. Use LINQ because you want shorter better readable and maintainable code.

Comment: I think the case for not using LINQ would have to be pretty specific performance wise, otherwise the benefits you get from readable code are pretty sizable.

Comment: Yeah I was a bit confused a bit when I read the post but I assumed the author meant "a faster way to do it" as in a shorter way to write it.

Comment: @Srikanth - You know that this isn't LINQ? This is a built-in method on `List<T>`.